# Restkit: RKRequest delegates not called

Tags: ios, web-services, delegates, restkit

I'm really stumped by this problem. I'm using Restkit to access a web service. Most of the operations are working fine, but the first two, intializeDevice and insertNewPatron, are not. For these, the asynchronous request is fired, but the delegate methods are never called. I have checked on the server, and there is no evidence of these calls being made. I can't tell what's different about these operations that makes them not work. Here is the class that makes the calls:

```
-(id)initForController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    self.vc=viewController;
    NSString *baseURL = @"https://xxxxxxxxx/APNS_WebService/rest/operations/";
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL];

    client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:url];
    client.disableCertificateValidation=YES;

    return self;
}

-(void)insertNewPatronWithCard:(NSString *)cardNumber PIN:(NSString *)pin NickName:(NSString *)nickname Device:(NSString *)deviceID{


    request = [client requestWithResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/insertNewPatron?cardNumber=%@&pin=%@&nickname=%@&deviceID=%@",cardNumber,pin,nickname,deviceID]];
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"insertNewPatron" forKey:@"operation"];
    request.params=params;
    request.delegate=self;
    [request sendAsynchronously];


}

-(void)initializeDeviceWithID:(NSString *)deviceID{



    request = [client requestWithResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/initializeDevice?deviceID=%@",deviceID]];
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"initializeDevice" forKey:@"operation"];
    request.params=params;
    request.delegate=self;
    [request sendAsynchronously];


}

-(void)updateDevicePreferencesWithDeviceID:(NSString *)deviceID DueDateNotice:(NSString *)dueDateNotice HoldsNotice:(NSString *)holdsNotice EventNotice:(NSString *)eventNotice{


    request = [client requestWithResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/updateDevicePreferences?deviceID=%@&dueDateNotice=%@&holdsNotice=%@&eventNotice=%@",deviceID,dueDateNotice,holdsNotice,eventNotice]];
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"updateDevicePreferences" forKey:@"operation"];
    request.params=params;
    request.delegate=self;
    [request sendAsynchronously];


}

-(void)removeUserWithCard:(NSString *)cardNumber{


    request = [client requestWithResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/removeUser?cardNumber=%@",cardNumber]];
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"removeUser" forKey:@"operation"];
    request.params=params;
    request.delegate=self;
   [request sendAsynchronously];


}

-(void)addEventWithDevice:(NSString *)deviceID EventID:(NSString *)eventID{



    request = [client requestWithResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/addEvent?deviceID=%@&eventID=%@",deviceID,eventID]];
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"addEvent" forKey:@"operation"];
    request.params=params;
    request.delegate=self;
    [request send];


}

-(void)removeEventWithDevice:(NSString *)deviceID EventID:(NSString *)eventID{


   request = [client requestWithResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/removeEvent?deviceID=%@&eventID=%@",deviceID,eventID]];
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"removeEvent" forKey:@"operation"];
    request.params=params;
    request.delegate=self;
     [request sendAsynchronously];

}

-(void)removeAllEventsWithDevice:(NSString *)deviceID{


    request = [client requestWithResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/removeAllEvents?deviceID=%@",deviceID]];
    request.delegate=self;
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"removeAllEvents" forKey:@"operation"];
    request.params=params;

   [request sendAsynchronously];


}
```

I notice that for the operations that don't work, in the Restkit logging, I get the message that says "Prepared GET UrlRequest", but NOT the one that says "Proceeding with request," which I see for the operations that work.

Comment: Did you check with a breakpoint that all the variables are correct? No nil delegate or something that you are missing? Are you doing the requests isolated or maybe one is being made at the same time as another call? Is probable that one of your calls is loosing the delegate in the process. I recommend to use blocks instead of delegate paradigm for async request to avoid race conditions.

Comment: This is a good idea; I'll try redesigning it to use blocks. However, as the server does not seem to be receiving the requests, it seems like it must be a deeper problem.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick, although I don't totally understand why. Make this into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You solved it changing the call to blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check with a breakpoint that all the variables are correct? No nil delegate or something that you are missing? Are you doing the requests isolated or maybe one is being made at the same time as another call?

Is probable that one of your calls is loosing the delegate in the process. I recommend to use **blocks** instead of delegate paradigm for async request to avoid race conditions.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It doesn't really explain why the server wasn't receiving the calls, but changing to blocks makes this work. Also, I see now that using blocks is a way better design for what I was trying to do.

Comment: Besides fixing your error, using blocks is better because improves your code readability.